# Submit with JQuery in firefox 3 & opera in a modal dialog box from SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, submit, fckeditor, simplemodal

I'm trying to submit a form who is rendered in a SimpleModal dialog, but my submit is never called when I'm using FF3 & Opera (Chrome, Safari and IE works). I use the following code:

```
function ShowModal(rendercontainerid, modalcontainerid, url) {
    if (url == '')
        return;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $(rendercontainerid).html(data);
        $(rendercontainerid).modal({ 
            close: false,
            containerId: modalcontainerid,
            onOpen: function(dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function() {
                        dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
            },
            onClose: function(dialog) {
                dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function() {
                        dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

function CloseDialog() {
    $.modal.close();
}

function SubmitAndClose(rendercontainerid) {
    $(rendercontainerid).find('form').submit();
    CloseDialog();
    window.location = window.location;
}

function AjaxSubmitAndClose(rendercontainerid) {
    var form = $(rendercontainerid).find('form');
    var url = $(form).attr('action');
    var postData = $(form).serializeArray();

    var options = {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: AjaxSubmitSucces
    };

    $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
}

function AjaxSubmitSucces(data) {
    if (data.ErrorMessage != '') {
        alert(data.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else if (data.RedirectUrl != '') {
        CloseDialog();
        window.location = data.RedirectUrl;
    }
}
```

I also tried to the jquery.form plugin for ajax posting but then you will see the formdata(An fckeditor) is in the initial values(it looks like it is cached).

Comment: After an update of jquery(1.5), SimpleModal(1.4.1) and jQuery Form(2.63) my ajaxSubmit doesn't fire the custom defined success delegate. Instead of that I'm getting the error that there is an semicolon missing. The controller(asp.net) gets the ajaxSubmit action and handles it ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the onShow callback:

```
onShow: function (dialog) {
  // bind form submit in dialog
  dialog.data.find('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff here
  });
}
```